# Laravel App - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: mysql, pdo, laravel-8

I recently was given a project to work on that is built with laravel 8. I don't have much experience with laravel and the previous developer didn't leave much documentation to say how to start the app properly so I've been reading up on what to do to get started. I cloned the project, ran `composer install` and renamed `.env.example` to `.env`. From here the little documentation written from the previous dev says to run `php artisan migrate`. However when running that, I get an error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`. I have seen a few posts on this site with some trouble shooting techniques, but so far nothing is working for me yet. My current `.env` DB section looks like:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

This is how it came by default and when I ran `php artisan migrate` I got `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`. I read around and saw that some folks changed `DB_HOST` to `localhost` instead of `mysql`. After I did that is when I started to get the connection refused error and now I'm a little lost. How can I find the proper host/port on Mac OS so I can run `php artisan migrate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because of you did not provide any database name in the .env file, before migration it is necessary to provide database name with their credentials

Please Create a database in phpmyadmin and fill out require parameter of database in env
Example.
created database name test in phpmyadmin then code will be like this

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME="database username here"
DB_PASSWORD="database password here"
```

If you do not have any password for database leave blank password field
Let me know if you have any confusion